# Getting overflow error for number 10000000000000000

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, solidity-0.8.x

```
 function withdraw (uint  _collateralVal) public payable{
 
// eligibleAmt = super.requestForLoan( _collateralVal*10**18);
payable(msg.sender).transfer( _collateralVal);
emit withdrawEvent(msg.sender,eligibleAmt);
  

 }
```

Error:

```
TypeError: overflow (argument="value", value=10000000000000000, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.6.2)

    at makeError (errors.ts:670:1)

    at assert (errors.ts:694:1)

    at assertArgument (errors.ts:706:1)

    at getBigInt (maths.ts:100:1)
    at NumberCoder.encode (number.ts:36:1)
    at array.ts:64:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (array.ts:47:1)
    at TupleCoder.encode (tuple.ts:62:1)
    at AbiCoder.encode (abi-coder.ts:195:1)
```

why getting overflow while using uint256? using etherjs.
js function call
await TreasuryContract.withdraw(10000000000000000);
Working fine while testing in remix

Answer (score 0):

Try value = "10000000000000000" as a string instead of 10000000000000000, it should work